# Amend custom URL for SSRS server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, server, sql-server-2016

I have a server running SSRS. Visiting the server URL directs to the intranet URL:
http://server/CloudReports/Pages/Folder.aspx

I believe the 'CloudReports' folder name was customised previously but where can I edit this?
I've looked in Reporting Services Configuration Manager and can't find anything.

Comment: [Configure a URL (Report Server Configuration Manager)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-url-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It should be the virtual folder in the "Web Portal URL" tab in Reporting Services Configuration Manager. Make sure you are connecting to the correct server, not a local dev server for example